# how to read a parquet file, in a standalone java code?

Tags: java, parquet

the parquet docs from cloudera shows examples of integration with pig/hive/impala. but in many cases I want to read the parquet file itself for debugging purposes.

is there a straightforward java reader api to read a parquet file ?

Thanks
Yang

Comment: This isn't a direct answer, but you may have some luck by going through the parquet-tools project that exposes a command line tool to read Parquet files and seeing what you can call from your own Java application. https://github.com/apache/incubator-parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30565510/how-to-read-and-write-mapstring-object-from-to-parquet-file-in-java-or-scala

Comment: @JeremyBeard That repo is empty as of 1/17

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Generate Parquet File Using Pure Java (Including Date & Decimal Types) And Upload to S3 \[Windows\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355038/how-to-generate-parquet-file-using-pure-java-including-date-decimal-types-an)

Answer (score 11):

Old method: (deprecated)

```
AvroParquetReader<GenericRecord> reader = new AvroParquetReader<GenericRecord>(file);
GenericRecord nextRecord = reader.read();
```

New method:

```
ParquetReader<GenericRecord> reader = AvroParquetReader.<GenericRecord>builder(file).build();
GenericRecord nextRecord = reader.read();
```

I got this from [here](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/c5561becfbc17bb1643e24faed87424a612ea7f1/parquet-avro/src/test/java/org/apache/parquet/avro/TestReadWrite.java#L107-L108) and have used this in my test cases successfully.

Comment: This doesn't work for me - I only get Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: <myclass> cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord

Answer (score 8):

You can use `AvroParquetReader` from parquet-avro library to read a parquet file as a set of AVRO `GenericRecord` objects.

Comment: Or specific ones (for speed).