# How to view a parquet file in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, parquet

I want to open a parquet file and view the contents of the table in Intellij. Is there a way to do this currently or with a plugin?

Comment: Why does it have to be Intellij?

Comment: Like, you could just write a simple java project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615511/how-to-read-a-parquet-file-in-a-standalone-java-code

Comment: A simple answer for your question is no, there is no plugin nor a way to do this in IntelliJ. On the other hands, there is the parquet-tools CLI that can help you manipulate parquet files from your shell. That said, I'm voting to close this question as being off topic for asking us to recommend or find a tool. Sorry Ben.

Comment: I would also like to know how to view it in intellij. for those who use intellij to develop scala projects and want to test things locally, it will be convenient to check the parquet files.

Comment: Relevant: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/BDIDE-2

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2019/10/16/meet-big-data-tools-spark-integration-and-zeppelin-notebooks-in-intellij-idea/ ```January 2020: Integration with HDFS (file explorer) and the Parquet viewer ``` so probably we will have something soon

Comment: It does work for me - but only some of the time :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for you is no, at least now.
But if the reason you want to view Parquet tables on Intellij is because you want to view Parquet file with GUI tool, I suggest you use tools [Bigdata File Viewer](https://github.com/Eugene-Mark/bigdata-file-viewer).

It's a desktop application to view [Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/) and also other binary format data like [ORC](https://orc.apache.org/) and [AVRO](https://avro.apache.org/). It's pure Java application so that can be run at Linux, Mac and also Windows.

It supports complex data type like array, map, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You need to install: Avro and Parquet Viewer plugin in order to view this kind of file:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12281-avro-and-parquet-viewer

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 9):

If you just want to open a Parquet file, it is part of the [Big Data Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/big-data-tools-support.html) plugin (JetBrain's official). Just install it and then double click the file it will open in the editor as a table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As @Pari said in a previous answer, you can download the [Avro and Parquet Viewer plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12281-avro-and-parquet-viewer). **Even for the community edition**.

But in order to see view the files, you need to go to the left-botton part of the IDE. Then click on `Avro and Parquet Viewer` and you can drag a file form the IDE navigator.

So, you will view your file. Click on `3` for visualizing the file as a table.

[image]

I mention this, since double clicking a file in the IDE navigator will show you the UFT-8 representation of a binary file.

FYI: You need to restart the IDE after installing.