# How to read parquet file in parallel with a java code

Tags: java, parquet

Is it possible to read a parquet file in parallel ?

I'm using something similar to what is described here (based on AvroParquetReader): [how to read a parquet file, in a standalone java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615511/how-to-read-a-parquet-file-in-a-standalone-java-code)
but this is done in sequence not in parallel.

Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

Still fresh to parquet files, I found opening the parquet file as Spark datasets to list parallelized stream to be faster:

```
// spark dataset to list parallel foreach
String PATH_SCHEMA = "s3a://" + bucket + "/" + key;
Path path = new Path(PATH_SCHEMA);

SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[1]").appName("example.com").getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> ds = spark.read().parquet(path.toString());
ds.collectAsList().parallelStream().forEach(Class::method);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found is to have an executor pool and every worker of this pool reads one of the parquet file.