# Outdated Hadoop dependency for reading/writing Parquet in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, parquet

I have a Java service writing and reading Parquet files using *parquet-avro 1.11.1*.

Now as you probably know this requires another dependency (which is not included in parquet-avro) for some hadoop classes, for example:

```
org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
```

I ended up using *hadoop-core 1.2.1*, which works. The thing is, this library is from **2013**, and it's the latest version! I wonder if there's a newer alternative?
I tried the following:

- [hadoop-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client)
- [hadoop-common](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common)

Both compile but don't work without a native Hadoop installation, which I'd like to avoid - I only want the classes needed for working with Parquet.

Comment: Take a look at the IntelliJ plugin that I wrote to read Parquet files - https://github.com/benwatson528/intellij-avro-parquet-plugin/blob/master/build.gradle. I had to fight with the same problems that you're encountering now. I avoid `Path` entirely by using `LocalInputFormat`. Ignore the local 1.11.1-SNAPSHOT JAR and just pretend I'm using 1.11.0.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59939309/read-local-parquet-file-without-hadoop-path-api might help you as it outlines my process for solving this problem.