# Java hadoop: check is .parquet file contains any value?

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm new to Hadoop and I wonderer: is there a way to check does `.parquet` file contains any value or not without executing spark query?

Comment: Parquet is independent of Spark, so you can view it without needing Spark. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615511/how-to-read-a-parquet-file-in-a-standalone-java-code for example.

Comment: In particular, you may find `parquet-tools` quite useful to view metadata and dump content of parquet files. https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/parquet-1.11.x/parquet-tools